# io.read() isn't working and makes my file immediately exit

Tags: error-handling, syntax, lua, compiler-errors, syntax-error

This works fine, but when I tried to make another one, it makes the lua file immediately exits

```
print("hai")
io.read()
```

```
local var = math.random()
print(math.sqrt(var))
if var >= 0 then
print(math.sqrt(3)
elseif var <= 0 then
print(var)
end
end
end
io.read()
```

I added second **io.read()** but the problem is still here. I changed from **io.read()** to ***os.execute*** "pause" but I still can't solve this problem

Comment: The code in the second block does not compile.

Comment: What do u mean? What should i do to fix my code? Can u tell me the problem here?

Comment: `print(math.sqrt(3)` needs a closing parenthesis.

Comment: oh ok thanks a lot